# How do use variable in the range() function to select a dynamic range?

Tags: python, range

I've got multiple file where I want to parse variable numbers of lines. Basically down to a line containing the string `Date:`.

The code I'm using is:

```
with open('MyFile.txt') as text:
    count=0
    i=0
    while i == 0:
        for line in text:
            count+=1
            if 'Date:' in line:
                i = count
                break
    head = [text.next() for x in range(i)]
```

I keep getting a `StopIteration` error and I can't figure out why. The type for `i` is an int, so I assumed that it would work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the complete error message.  Also please fix your code indentation.

Comment: `text.next()` raises the `StopIteration`, not the `range()`.

Comment: And try to make sure that your indentation is correct (that `with` is at the same level than the rest of the code, and I'm pretty sure that's not correct)

Comment: The code is indented correctly when I edit it.  However, when I click post it gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` gives you a `StopIteration` because you've already consumed it in your loop (you aren't starting at the beginning again). Try adding to the list as you go, instead of in another loop at the end:

```
head = []
with open('MyFile.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        if 'Date:' in line:
            break
        head.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [itertools.takewhile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to get all the lines until there is a `Date:` inside:

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open('MyFile.txt') as text:
    data = list(takewhile(lambda line: 'Date:' not in line, text))

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what version of python you have on python 3 the following code work\

```
   text = open('text.txt', 'r')
    count=0
    i=0
    while i == 0:
        for line in text:
            count+=1
            if 'Date:' in line:
                i = count
                break
    head = [text.next() for x in range(i)]
```